# How can we display datas according to button clicks in mainpage ....if many filteration method is applied in ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When someone Logs in first of all i want to **show the currentUserData in the table body**.
then when clicks on "**Today**" button, table should be show the "**todayData**"....when clicks on "**This Week**" button, table should be show the "**thisWeekData**"....etc....

**references**

..................

**userData** = all datas available in database,

**todayData** = filtered data from "userData" with current day (function calls after clicking "Today" button from main page),

**thisWeekData** = filtered data from "userData" with current week (function calls after clicking "This Week" button from main page)

**thisMonthData** = filtered data from "userData" with current Month (function calls after clicking "This Month" button from main page),

**customData** = filtered data from "userData" between dates (function calls after clicking "Custom" button from main page),

**dropDownUserData** = filtered data from "userData" (function calls after clicking any user from Drop down menu "Today" available in main page),

**currentUserData** = displaying datas of users by deviding into pages

```
      {

        // ️checking whether any current day datas available or not...if, displaying the datas
         todayData.length > 0 ?

          todayData.map((user, id) =>
            <tr key={id} className='table-row'>
              <td className='table-item'>{user.date}</td>
              <td className='table-item'>{user.from}</td>
              <td className='table-item'>{user.to}</td>
              <td className='table-item'>{user.duration}</td>
              <td className='table-item'>{user.hangup}</td>
              <td className='table-item'>{user.action}</td>
            </tr>)

          :

          // ️checking whether any this week datas available or not...if, displaying the datas
          thisWeekData.length > 0 ?

            thisWeekData.map((user, id) =>
              <tr key={id} className='table-row'>
                <td className='table-item'>{user.date}</td>
                <td className='table-item'>{user.from}</td>
                <td className='table-item'>{user.to}</td>
                <td className='table-item'>{user.duration}</td>
                <td className='table-item'>{user.hangup}</td>
                <td className='table-item'>{user.action}</td>
              </tr>
            )

            :

            // ️checking whether any this month datas available or not...if, displaying the datas
            thisMonthData.length > 0 ?

              thisMonthData.map((user, id) =>
                <tr key={id} className='table-row'>
                  <td className='table-item'>{user.date}</td>
                  <td className='table-item'>{user.from}</td>
                  <td className='table-item'>{user.to}</td>
                  <td className='table-item'>{user.duration}</td>
                  <td className='table-item'>{user.hangup}</td>
                  <td className='table-item'>{user.action}</td>
                </tr>
              )

              :

              // ️checking whether any custom selected datas available or not...if, displaying the datas
              customData.length > 0 ?

                customData.map((user, id) =>
                  <tr key={id} className='table-row'>
                    <td className='table-item'>{user.date}</td>
                    <td className='table-item'>{user.from}</td>
                    <td className='table-item'>{user.to}</td>
                    <td className='table-item'>{user.duration}</td>
                    <td className='table-item'>{user.hangup}</td>
                    <td className='table-item'>{user.action}</td>
                  </tr>
                )

                :

                // ️checking whether any datas related to selected user from drop down is available or not...if, displaying the datas
                dropDownUserData ?

                  dropDownUserData.map((user, id) =>
                    <tr key={id} className='table-row'>
                      <td className='table-item'>{user.date}</td>
                      <td className='table-item'>{user.from}</td>
                      <td className='table-item'>{user.to}</td>
                      <td className='table-item'>{user.duration}</td>
                      <td className='table-item'>{user.hangup}</td>
                      <td className='table-item'>{user.action}</td>
                    </tr>
                  )

                  :

                  // ️checking whether any datas available in database or not...if, displaying the datas
                  currentUserData && currentUserData.length > 0 ?
                    // ️Search details

                    currentUserData.filter((value) => {
                      if (searchInput === '') {
                        return value
                      }

                      else if (value.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase())) {
                        return value
                      }
                    })

                      // ️Displaying datas on table

                      .map((user, id) =>
                        <tr key={id} className='table-row'>
                          <td className='table-item'>{user.date}</td>
                          <td className='table-item'>{user.from}</td>
                          <td className='table-item'>{user.to}</td>
                          <td className='table-item'>{user.duration}</td>
                          <td className='table-item'>{user.hangup}</td>
                          <td className='table-item'>{user.action}</td>
                        </tr>
                      ) : 'Loading'

      }

    </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  //️ Setting state for showing the required datas when filtering
  const [showUserData, setShowUserData] = useState(false)
  const [showTodayData, setShowTodayData] = useState(false)
  const [showWeekData, setShowWeekData] = useState(false)
  const [showMonthData, setShowMonthData] = useState(false)
  const [showCustomData, setShowCustomData] = useState(false)
  const [showDropDownData, setShowDropDownData] = useState(false)
```

**setstates as *true or false* as per the requirements in the onClick functions**

**eg:** for Today button click
setShowTodayData(true)
setShowWeekData(false)
setShowDropDownData(false) etc.....

**app.js**

```
 {
<tbody className='table-body'>
    
// ️Displaying all datas by deviding into pages
    
              {showUserData && currentUserData.filter((value) => {

                if (searchInput === '') {
                  return value
                }
    
                else if (value.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase())) {
                  return value
                }
              })
                .map((user, id) => {
                  return <tr key={id} className='table-row'>
                    <td className='table-item'>{user.date}</td>
                    <td className='table-item'>{user.from}</td>
                    <td className='table-item'>{user.to}</td>
                    <td className='table-item'>{user.duration}</td>
                    <td className='table-item'>{user.hangup}</td>
                    <td className='table-item'>{user.action}</td>
                  </tr>
                })
    
              }
    
// ️checking whether any datas related to selected user from drop down is available or not...if, displaying the datas
    
              {showDropDownData && dropDownUserData.map((user, id) =>
                <tr key={id} className='table-row'>
                  <td className='table-item'>{user.date}</td>
                  <td className='table-item'>{user.from}</td>
                  <td className='table-item'>{user.to}</td>
                  <td className='table-item'>{user.duration}</td>
                  <td className='table-item'>{user.hangup}</td>
                  <td className='table-item'>{user.action}</td>
                </tr>)
              }
    
// ️checking whether any Today datas available or not...if, displaying the datas
    
              {showTodayData && todayData.map((user, id) =>
                <tr key={id} className='table-row'>
                  <td className='table-item'>{user.date}</td>
                  <td className='table-item'>{user.from}</td>
                  <td className='table-item'>{user.to}</td>
                  <td className='table-item'>{user.duration}</td>
                  <td className='table-item'>{user.hangup}</td>
                  <td className='table-item'>{user.action}</td>
                </tr>)
              }
    
// ️checking whether any This week datas available or not...if, displaying the datas
    
              {showWeekData && thisWeekData.map((user, id) =>
                <tr key={id} className='table-row'>
                  <td className='table-item'>{user.date}</td>
                  <td className='table-item'>{user.from}</td>
                  <td className='table-item'>{user.to}</td>
                  <td className='table-item'>{user.duration}</td>
                  <td className='table-item'>{user.hangup}</td>
                  <td className='table-item'>{user.action}</td>
                </tr>)
              }
    
// ️checking whether any This month datas available or not...if, displaying the datas
    
              {
                showMonthData && thisMonthData.map((user, id) =>
                  <tr key={id} className='table-row'>
                    <td className='table-item'>{user.date}</td>
                    <td className='table-item'>{user.from}</td>
                    <td className='table-item'>{user.to}</td>
                    <td className='table-item'>{user.duration}</td>
                    <td className='table-item'>{user.hangup}</td>
                    <td className='table-item'>{user.action}</td>
                  </tr>)
              }
    
 // ️checking whether any Custom datas available or not...if, displaying the datas
    
              {
                showCustomData && customData.map((user, id) =>
                  <tr key={id} className='table-row'>
                    <td className='table-item'>{user.date}</td>
                    <td className='table-item'>{user.from}</td>
                    <td className='table-item'>{user.to}</td>
                    <td className='table-item'>{user.duration}</td>
                    <td className='table-item'>{user.hangup}</td>
                    <td className='table-item'>{user.action}</td>
                  </tr>)
              }
            </tbody>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create memoized `todayData`, `thisWeekData`, and `thisMonthData`.

```
const todayData = useMemo(() => {
    ...
},[userData])

const thisWeekData = useMemo(() => {
    ...
},[userData])

const thisMonthData = useMemo(() => {
    ...
},[userData])
```

Then create a `showingData` state that would become render reference data

```
    const [showingData, setShowingData] = useState();

    render (
        ...
        {showingData.map((data) => {
    
        })}
        ...
    )
```

Finally, at the buttons, assign the data by using `setState`:

```
    render (
        ...
        <botton onClick={() => setShowingData(todayData)}>
           Today
        </button>
        <botton onClick={() => setShowingData(thisWeekData)}>
            This Week
        </button>
        <botton onClick={() => setShowingData(thisMonth)}>
            This Month
        </button>
        ...
    )
```

And the example is as follows:

```js
function makeUserData() {
    const daysInMonth = [];

    const monthDate = moment().startOf('isoWeek');

    _.times(monthDate.daysInMonth(), function (n) {
        const hours = Math.random() * (0 + 12) + 0
        const minutes = Math.random() * (0 + 60) + 0
        const start = moment(n).set("hour", hours).set("minute", minutes);
        const end = moment(start).add(Math.random() * (0 + 30) + 0, 'minutes');

        daysInMonth.push({
            date: monthDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY'),
            name: monthDate.format('dddd'),
            from: start.format("HH:mm"),
            to: end.format("HH:mm"),
            duration: `${parseInt((moment(end) - moment(start))/60000)} minutes`
        });
        monthDate.add(1, 'day');
    });
    return daysInMonth;
}

const { useEffect, useState, useMemo } = React;

function App() {
    const [showingData, setShowingData] = useState([]);

    const today = useMemo(() => moment());

    const userData = useMemo(() => {
        return makeUserData();
    },[]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setShowingData(userData);
    }, [userData]);

    const todayData = useMemo(() => {
        return userData.filter((data) => data.date === today.format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
    }, [today, userData]);

    const thisWeekData = useMemo(() => {
        const startOfWeek = today.clone().startOf('isoWeek');
        const endOfWeek = today.clone().endOf('isoWeek');
        return userData.filter((data) => {
            return (new Date(data.date) >= new Date(startOfWeek) && new Date(data.date) <= new Date(endOfWeek))
        });
    }, [today, userData]);

    const thisMonthData = useMemo(() => {
        const startDate = today.clone().startOf('month');
        return userData.filter((data) => new Date(data.date) >= new Date(startDate));
    }, [today, userData]);

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => setShowingData(userData)}>
                Current Data
            </button>
            <button onClick={() => setShowingData(todayData)}>
                Today
            </button>
            <button onClick={() => setShowingData(thisWeekData)}>
                This Week
            </button>
            <button onClick={() => setShowingData(thisMonthData)}>
                This Month
            </button>
            <table>
                <thead>
                     <tr>
                         <th>Date</th>
                         <th>Name</th>
                         <th>From</th>
                         <th>To</th>
                         <th>Duration</th>
                     </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {showingData.map((data, index) => (
                     <tr key={index}>
                         <td>{data.date}</td>
                         <td>{data.name}</td>
                         <td>{data.from}</td>
                         <td>{data.to}</td>
                         <td>{data.duration}</td>
                     </tr>
                ))}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```